# admin menu item not displaying

Tags: 7, routes

I am developing a module which has an admin menu entry in Drupal 7. The issue I am having is that the menu item is not showing up in the admin menu. I have looked at the docs and scoured google for why this might be happening but nothing I try seems to work.

Here is my hook_menu() implementation:

```
$items['admin/config/people/accomplishments'] = array(
  'title'            => 'Accomplishments',
  'description'      => 'Configure the accomplishments system.',
  'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments'   => array('accomplishments_admin_form'),
  'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
  'file'             => 'accomplishments.admin.inc',
  'type'             => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
```

I have tried flushing the cache and reinstalling the module but nothing works. I do notice that when I specifically go to the url admin/config/people/accomplishments I get a permission denied error - which doesn't make sense to me as I am logged in as user 1 and I have assigned access privileges to the administrator role.

The module I am developing is creating a new entity so I don't know if this might have a baring on this as I have never created an entity before, but I don't think it should.

Any ideas as to what I am overlooking or what the cause might be? I am going crazy here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the path your using is "admin/config/people/accomplishments"
Make sure that the users that need to have access to this menu item have sufficient permissions in administering people or use another path

Last make sure you flushed the drupal caches so the changes are applied. Drupal only calculates the menu items once and then it caches them